# Isotope - How to fill the entire height of the container

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use js Isotope library to develope a page that shows a variable number of items/boxes.
This set of boxes should always fill in a column the entire height of the available space (let's say the container) regardless of the number of the items - of course automatically changing the height of the single item.

I mean: at the first step if I need to show 3 boxes, the vertical space should be divided in 3 equal spaces. On a click in a box I set a different filter for Isotope object and the filtered items should fill the same vertical space too.

No problems for the filtering request, but I have a trouble with the layout: the first try was to set the *'vertical'* *layout-mode* but the contents did not fill the available height.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this using CSS, flexbox in particular. For more details see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

The only mandatory requirement is to set a height for the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 200px; /* For demo purpose */
  background-color: green; /* For demo purpose */
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue; /* For demo purpose */
  border: 1px red solid; /* For demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that it seems the height of the isotope container is set by the script itself - i'm not able to overwrite this set :(

Comment: @SteMMo that's ok. As long as there is a height it should work. No matter what the value for the height is.

Comment: I put a sample code on codepen.io : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stemmo/pen/xxGpGEQ)